# How to link to html page at specific ID bookmark?

Tags: draw.io

Using Diagrams.net (draw.io), I would like to link specific elements to web pages.  This is easily accomplished currently by creating a link for the element (say a rectangle).

However, I would like to navigate directly to a specific **id** bookmark in the HTML page.  I cannot seem to get that to work.

For example, if I try to use this syntax (which works in the browser location bar):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada#Geography

I will be taken to the main page:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada

However, the goal is to go to the **"Geography"** section of this page.

I have also tried the *json* syntax without any success:

> data:action/json,{"actions":[{"open":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada#Geography"}]}

I have also played with different action syntax such as:

> data:action/json,{"actions":[{"open":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada"},{"scroll":{"tags":["Geography"]}}]}

Note: I'm using the diagrams.net desktop version 14.1.8.

Thank you for taking the time to read this question.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

On Windows this only seems to work if the browser isn't already open. There is not much we can do to fix this as we're passing the link to the OS.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  Unfortunately, it does not appear you are calling the OS directly.   For example, from a windows cmd prompt if you type:

`start /max https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada#Geography`

Then the proper website page and bookmark gets opened in your default browser.